# How to use "conditionals" without using IF statements?

Tags: java, if-statement

I have this project that we can't use IF statements for. For example, if something is connected this needs to happen. So I made a variable connected and initialised it to 0. To say, if something is connected then it's 1 and if it's not its 0. But i cant figure out how to write the statements to say that without using if statements.

```
public void removeBattery(){
    connected = 0;
    cameraCharge = cameraCharge * connected;
}
```

But this isn't working in the tests when I call the method. Even though, its multiplied by 0 its still showing a different value.

```
public double drain(double minutes) {
        double drain = Math.min((cameraPowerConsumption * minutes), 
                batteryCharge);
        batteryCharge = Math.max(batteryCharge - drain, 0);
        totalDrain += drain;
        return drain;
    }
```

And here if its connected this is how you calculate drain, but when you call the removeBattery method it shouldnt be connected anymore and the drain should be 0. Im so confused.

Comment: "*I have this project that we can't use IF statements for*" - sorry but what kind of a project is that? Or is it homework?

Comment: Can you use the ternary operator instead of if()?   https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/Java-Ternary-Operator-Nested-Examples-Return-if-else-symbol-void-null

Comment: Are you allowed to use `try...catch` blocks?

Comment: What is the "different value"? What's the type of the member fields? Can you use `switch/case`? Can you use `cond ? then : else`? Subclasses?

Comment: class homework, the logic is flying over my head. I just can't figure out to multiple the connected variable when applicable.

Comment: To be clear, you're allowed to ask for homework help here (as far as StackOverflow is concerned, your teacher may have other opinions.) But in a case like this where there is an arbitrary restriction, it helps to know more of the context - like if there's a concept they're covering, that they want you to use instead. "Use arithmetic to replace if statements" isn't unheard of, but it's not something I'd expect.

Comment: you could consider method overloading. by having one method provide a "default" value of zero, then the other which takes a value can be set to whatever other value you want

Comment: I think we are not allowed to use anything we haven't learned yet. So I cant use these options sorry. I was told there was a simpler way to do it with integers

Comment: to be honest, I might need a better overview of your homework to even give a good suggestions. All I can see is your removeBattery method and drain method, I cant tell how you use it overall, and if the method can be implemented another way

Comment: »we are not allowed to use anything we haven't learned yet« please tell us, what you have learned so far :) otherwise, we cannot possibly give the correct answer

Comment: are you eventually mixing up  `cameraCharge` and `batteryCharge`?

Comment: ^This sounds like it might be it. That makes sense, while battery is not connected, it cannot drain

Answer (score 0):

The logical AND operator && can be included in your code to examine the status of the declared variable 'connected'. When the value of 'connected' is 1, the expression 'connected == 1 &&' will evaluate to true, while it will return a false result if the value is something else. This can be incorporated in the 'drain' method to control the calculation of the drain in response to the status of 'connected'. For example, it can be written as such:

```
public double drain(double minutes) {
        double drain = connected == 1 ? Math.min((cameraPowerConsumption * minutes), 
                batteryCharge) : 0;
        batteryCharge = Math.max(batteryCharge - drain, 0);
        totalDrain += drain;
        return drain;
    }
```

If the connection is established, the amount of drain will be determined as normal. On the other hand, if the connection is not made, the drain value will be set to zero.